# Словообразование наречий

Tags: словообразование, морфология, наречия

Почему производящей основой слов "надолго" и "слегка" являются слова "долгий" и "лёгкий", а не "долго" и "легко" соответственно? Говоря простым языком, почему лёгкий → слегка, а не лёгкий → легко → слегка; долгий → надолго, а не долгий → долго → надолго?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наречия ***надолго*** и ***слегка*** образованы **от краткой формы прилагательного,** хотя в качестве мотивирующего слова указана полная форма: легкий ― легок ― слегка, долгий ― долог ― надолго.

**Раньше краткие формы склонялись**, и приставки ― это бывшие предлоги. Склонение сохранилось в народно-поэтической речи: добра молодца, красну девицу.

**Розенталь:** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=68#pp68

Пишутся слитно (в одно слово) наречия, образованные **соединением предлога-приставки с краткой формой прилагательного:** влево, задолго, намертво, докрасна, издавна, справа, подолгу, попусту, неподалёку.

Также: Наречия с приставками в-, за-, на-, образованные **от кратких форм прилагательных,** имеют на конце букву о: вправо, засветло, накрепко.

Проверить конечную гласную можно с помощью сущ. ср. рода: влево ― в окно, слева ― с окна.